# Conditional operator AND in Simple Expression doesnt work in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I want to show log only if both param **id** and **name** value are `null` in  rest url using filter but for all the cases it got executed

The block should be executed only if below  case

```
http://localhost:9098/myapi/student?age=12
```

But  filter is always got executed even condition fails

for the url cases like below

```
http://localhost:9098/myapi/student?id=100&age=16

http://localhost:9098/myapi/student?name=john&age=12
```

Here the id/name param is not null
Code

```
<filter id="_filter1">
                <simple>" ${in.header.name} == null and ${in.header.id}==null"</simple>
          <log  message="Both param are null"/>
 </filter>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you study the documentation of the simple language, then it says that you must use space around the operators. And it should not be in a quote either

This

```
<simple>" ${in.header.name} == null and ${in.header.id}==null"</simple>
```

Should be

```
<simple>${in.header.name} == null and ${in.header.id} == null</simple>
```

Comment: thank you :) Claus Ibsen i tried without quotes previously. it was space issue. It has been solved :)